# jQuery undefined is not a function only in one twig file

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm getting the "undefined is not a function" error only on this single position. I get this at var dropdown and cant identify the error.

At other sites i include this .js is no error.

navbar.js

```
 function insertModules($parent, modules) {
        for (var i = 0; i < modules.length; i++) {
            var module = modules[i];
            if (module.subitems) {
                var $dropdown = $('\
          <li class="dropdown">\
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">' + module.title + ' <b class="caret"></b></a>\
            <ul class="dropdown-menu"></ul>\
          </li>\
        ');
                $parent.append($dropdown);
                var subParent = $dropdown.find('ul');
                insertModules(subParent, module.subitems);
            }
            else {
                insertModule($parent, module);
            }
        }
    }
```

call of insertModules

```
    // set modules
if (ubnav.authenticated) {
            var $parent = $('#ubnav-modules');
            insertModules($parent, BPNAV_MODULES);

        $parent = $('#ubnav-modules-alphabetical');
        for (var i = 0; i < BPNAV_MODULES_ALPHABETICAL.length; i++) {
            var module = BPNAV_MODULES_ALPHABETICAL[i];
            if (module.name !== ubnav.currentModule) {
                insertModule($parent, module);
            }
            else {
                var $currentModule = $('#ubnav-current-module');
                var $currentModuleParent = $currentModule.parent();
                insertModule($currentModuleParent, module);
                $currentModule.remove();
                $currentModuleParent.find('li.active').addClass('current-module').addClass('hidden-lg');
            }
        }
    }

 function insertModule($parent, module) {
    var href = (module.url) ? module.url : null;
    if (!href) {
        if (module.location === 'bp') href = ubnav.linkModuleBaseBP;
        else if (module.location === 'ip') href = ubnav.linkModuleBaseIP;
        else if (module.location === 'bp2') href = ubnav.linkModuleBaseBP2;
        else if (module.location === 'meteor') href = ubnav.linkModuleBaseMeteor;

        href += (module.suffixPath) ? module.suffixPath : module.name;
    }
    var current = (ubnav.currentModule === module.name) ? ' class="active"' : '';
    $parent.append('<li' + current + '><a href="' + href + '">' + module.title + '</a></li>');
}
```

Comment: can you show the code that calls `insertModules` - we dont know if that is wrapped in a closure to tell if jQuery is initialised yet or indeed if $parent is a jQuery variable and not a dom element. can you use console to tell what var is null?

Comment: If i set dropdown null, there comes another error that i cant use the .find function later. but the undefined is not a function is gone then.

Answer (score 1):

You have typed `insertModule($parent, module)` but your function is called `insertModules()`

Same with: `insertModule($currentModuleParent, module);`

Comment: Ahh now I see you added code of a function called `insertModule`

Answer (score 0):

I isolated and solved the problem.
It was a bootstrap.min.js file that was included too much.